# JQuery DELETE request to C# API -> HTTP status code 405

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a WebApi written in C# on one server and a webpage on another server that is trying to send a DELETE request using JQuery:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#Save").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "DELETE",
            url: "https://chad-test4.clas.uconn.edu/api/Employees/1",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("Response recieved");
                console.log("Success: " + JSON.stringify(data));

            },

            error: function() {
                console.log("Failed")
            }

          //  data: {"id": 1 }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

This is my controller:

```
// DELETE: api/Employees/5
    //[ResponseType(typeof(JsonObjectContract))]
    public HttpResponseMessage Deleteemployee(int id)
    {
        employee employee = db.employees.Find(id);
        var jsonid = employee.id;


        if (jsonid == null)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Error: Employee does not exist.");
        }

        db.employees.Remove(employee);
        db.SaveChanges();

        var Success = this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Success");
        Success.Content = new StringContent("{ Success: Success }", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        return Success;
    }
```

The Response I receive in the console is:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://chad-test4.clas.uconn.edu/api/Employees/1. 
Invalid HTTP status code 405
create.htm:41 Failed
```

After doing research on the topic, I changed my Web.Config headers to the suggested text:

```
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <remove name="WebDAVModule"/>
  <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
</modules>
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <clear />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE,   OPTIONS" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

I am still getting the same response. Any suggestions are appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP 405 status code is not "Bad Request" but "Method not allowed".

In your WebApiConfig.cs file the route that you have configured for your controller should specify what HTTP verbs your controller will accept in the action attribute. Make sure that the type: in your javascript is set to the matching HTTP verb in the action of your route.

Your method in the controller should probably also have an attribute describing the verb it services e.g. [HttpPost], or [HttpDelete].

For example, here is the route configuration for a small Api I have...

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Registers the WebAPI routes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="config">The configuration.</param>
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "SOAInboundApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}",
            defaults: new { controller = "SOAInbound", action = "Post", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "LogFileApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}",
            defaults: new { controller = "LogFile", action = "Get", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

I have a Default, which just puts up a static view that explains how to use my Api, a SOAInbound which accepts HTTP Post, and a LogFile which accepts HTTP Get.

Comment: So in this?: config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            ); I'm not sure what to change here to do that

Comment: Add action attribute to new e.g. new = { controler = "NameOfYourControler", action = "Delete", id= RouteParameter.Optional }

Comment: Do i then need to change my controller from HttpResponseMessage to ActionResult?

Comment: I wouldn't think it will make a difference since you are not using the return value.

Answer (score -1):

The 405 code It is related to "HTPP bad request", this is a error of REST API, no, jQuery.

I recommend this tip to solution: https://praneeth4victory.wordpress.com/2011/09/29/405-method-not-allowed/

I suggest you move your question to C# tag.